# How to use ssh2_exec with php to run nodejs proccess

Tags: php, node.js

I'm making a PHP script that should be run via SSH2.

My current code:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('localhost', 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', '******');


$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "killall nodejs");
$errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);




$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "cd /var/www/a/ && nohup nodejs chat.js &");
$errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);

// Enable blocking for both streams
stream_set_blocking($errorStream, true);
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

// Whichever of the two below commands is listed first will receive its appropriate output.  The second command receives nothing
echo "Output: <b>" . stream_get_contents($stream);
echo "</b><hr /><br />Error: <b>" . stream_get_contents($errorStream).'</b><br /> <hr/>';

// Close the streams        
fclose($errorStream);
fclose($stream);
```

I do not know why, but it does not work. It just doesn't do anything with the `chat.js` file.

Comment: also web freezes after I run this code.